# Firebase read permissions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

So I've set up a simple db/web form to collect some user data. Rn I am trying to figure out the rules thing but I am running into this problem - if my `read` flag is set to `true` then I can simply run this in the console

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref();

ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
   console.log(snapshot.val());
}, function (error) {
   console.log("Error: " + error.code);
});
```

and expose the users which should not be the possibility. If I set `read` to `false` then I cant access the DB upfront to validate if email address is unique or not. I guess I need to achieve 2 things:

- Prevent db snooping through the dev tools running any snippets
- Make sure email address is unique.

p.s. My currents rules (prevent delete, prevent read, make sure POST request has certain fields):

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
        ".read": false,
        "$uid": {
         ".write": "!data.exists()",
         ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'country', 'amount'])"
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid duplicates you will want a validation check in the DB rather than reading data from the client and checking (you can't trust the client).

Since there is no easy way to check for duplicate child values in a firebase base collection, you will need a separate collection to track emails and then validate your emails against that, i.e.:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
       ".read": false,
       "$uid": {
         ".write": "!data.exists()",
         ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'country', 'amount'])",
         "email": {
           ".validate": "!root.child('emails').child(newData.val()).exists()"
         }
       }
    },
    "emails": {
       ".read": false,
       ".write": "!data.exists()"
    }
  }
}
```

You will then need to write the users' emails to the email collection as the users are added, e.g.:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('emails/'+email);
ref.set(uid)
```